# Como listar mais de 50 vídeos do Youtube utilizando cURL

Tags: php, api, youtube

Estou precisando retornar todos os vídeos de um determinado usuário do youtube, mas a minha função atual só retorna 50, que é o máximo permitido pela API. existe algum método de fazer isto?

```
$cURL = curl_init(sprintf('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/%s/uploads?start-index=1&max-results=50&orderby=published', 'nerineitzke'));
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$return = curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($return);

$i = 0;
foreach($xml->entry AS $video):
    $titulo = (string)$video->title;
    echo "$titulo <br/><br/>";
    $i++;
endforeach;

echo $i; // i = 50
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No URL existe o parâmetro `start-index`. Se ele estiver com o valor 1, serão trazidos os resultados de 1 até 50. Se ele estiver com o valor 2, serão trazidos os resultados de 2 até 51. E assim por diante.

Você pode fazer um loop que troca o valor do `start-index`, similar ao que você já fez no sprintf (colocando um `%s`), e rodar as queries de 50 em 50:

- Primeira iteração (1-50): `start-index=1`
- Segunda iteração (50-100): `start-index=50`
- ...

Para saber se existem mais páginas disponíveis, você pode procurar pelo parâmetro `<link rel="next" />` dentro do XML. Se ele existir, é sinal que há mais uma página com resultados, e você pode continuar o loop.

[Documentação do start-index](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?csw=1#start-indexsp)
[Documentação do totalResults e link next](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?csw=1#youtube_data_api_tag_openSearch:totalResults)

Comment: Sim, pensei nisso também, mas o problema é que não tem um retorno do número máximo de vídeos, então como faria para identificar que o próximo loop contem vídeos, e se contem 50 ou menos?

Comment: No começo do XML tem um tag que diz o total de resultados. Aqui: `<openSearch:totalResults>1128</openSearch:totalResults>`. Você pode se basear neste valor para fazer o cálculo.

Comment: Em todo caso, recomendo que você leia na documentação a parte sobre "Pagination and total result counts". A API não garante que esse número seja exato. Além disso, existe uma limitação fixa para o máximo de vídeos que podem ser carregados (mesmo paginando).

Comment: Ah, agora descobri: existe um parâmetro no XML chamado `<link rel="next" />`. Se ele estiver presente, é sinal que existe mais uma página. Se ele não estiver, você pode parar o loop. Abraços

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar JSON para pegar os valores mais facilmente, basta apenas colocar o parâmetro **alt=jsonc** na url.

Exemplo:

```
$json_url = file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/nerineitzke/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&start-index=1&max-results=50&orderby=published');

$json = json_decode($json_url);

$totalItens = $json->data->totalItems; // Mostra o total de itens cadastrados.

$videos = $json->data->items;

$i = 1;
foreach($videos as $video){ 
    echo $i . ' - ' . $video->title . '<br>';
    $i++;
}
```